# How can I save an email sent using Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We have auditing requirements that may require us to go back and keep a copy of the email sent out. We're using Amazon SES to send out emails.

Is there any way to retain logs about the email and its contents or should I simply cc the email to some other email account to be used for auditing and trouble shooting later?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) which keeps track of all APIs including SES. When you enable CloudTrail for SES, all your activity is stored in a S3 bucket which you can retrieve anytime you want.

Take a look at: [Logging Amazon SES API Calls By Using AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)

Comment: This does not work for my scenario, since I have attachments also that I need to track and be able to dig out the emails later.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a native feature within SES for keeping a copy of sent emails. But there is a feature for storing a copy on S3 for received emails. So if you take your idea of cc'ing or bcc'ing an email box you control then you could follow this [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html). Its a bit of hack but its low effort.

Comment: unfortunately this requires that my domain is managed by Amazon S3. Otherwise this seems to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @AbhinavGujjar Does it have to be your domain? How about making an audit domain like audit-example.com or something.  Otherwise you might need to look into tools that integrate at the DNS level.  I believe Google Apps has something that's tied in at the DNS level.

Comment: Ideally I don't want this data going to some domain outside my control. Sigh - basically it appears that its easier for me to simply cc it to another email and just automate the back on that using google scripts. I'm also wary of adding too many Amazon infrastructure dependencies when I absolutely don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful to someone, consider using [Amazon SES event destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/event-destinations-manage.html) as a solution for this task.